# How to obtain the reference of a button inside a datagrid in the viewmodel in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism

i have a datagrid declared in the xaml as follows:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="ProductsForProjectDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products.ProductsForProject}">
                  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DeleteTemplate" Width="10*">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Button x:Name="DeleteProductButton" Command="{Binding DeleteProductCommand}" CommandParameter="Products.SelectedProduct" >

                            <Button.Content>

                                <Image x:Name="DeleteProductImage" Visibility="Visible" Height="20" Source="C:\Documents and Settings\DELETE.GIF" Width="20"/>
                            </Button.Content> 
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Product}" Header="Product Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="40*"/>                          

        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

and in the viewModel i've to link the button to a command, i can get the reference to the datagrid using this,

```
_dlgProducts.ProductsForProjectDataGrid
```

where _dlgproducts is the object,
now how can i get a reference to the delete button,
once i get the reference i can bind a command to it,
i need something like

```
_dlgProducts.ProductsForProjectDataGrid.DeleteProductButton
```

or something, im not sure how to get it...

Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure to understand... what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ken2k i want the reference of the button in viewmodel..

Comment: That's your problem: you're not supposed to have **any** reference to the View part (buttons, grid...) in the view model. You have an architecture design issue here.

Comment: @ken2k i think i was not clear, ok after the gridview i have a button,
wat i do for the button in the viewmodel is,

_dlgProducts.AddButton.Command = this.AddCommandCommand, im trying to do the same for the button inside the datagrid

Comment: Why are you trying to add the command with code? It looks like you are already adding the command in your xaml (`Command="{Binding DeleteProductCommand}"`). Are you not setting your `DataContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding inside `DataTemplate` in `DataGrid` in Silverlight doesn't work as you would expect. You need to use `DataContextProxy`. See sample here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what your problem is. You want to set the command for a `Button` in the view model (which is by the way breaking your mvvm...) but you have the delete command bound to the button in XAML. If i understand correctly your binding is not working and you want to do it in code behind. If that is so please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999352/icommand-not-working-in-datagrid-celltemplate) question and the answer. Two more things:

- when you get it working your `CommandParameter` binding should look similiar to this `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`
- you'd better add your delete image to the app resources and use the pack/component syntax for the `Source` property, ie like [here](http://blog.meidianto.com/2009/10/13/working-with-imagesource-on-silverlight-3/)